# Is it possible to dynamicly zip files before downloading from another servers?

Tags: javascript, zip

I am wondering is it possible to write browser extension or simple Java Script code, which having a list of URLs to different location, could zip everything together.

I mean...

For instance...having 3 different image files on:

- http://example1.com/a.png
- http://example22.com/b.png
- http://example333.com/c.png

Is it possible to download all of them as zipped files archive images.zip by Java Script code on http://mysite.com ?

I have found [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/), however I don't know how use it to load files from different servers.

Comment: are you referring to Javascript code on the server side or on the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at this code: I have assembled a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5asM/14/) for you to get started from there. Scroll down to the last lines of the code.

First we need to laod the images into `<img>` tags. then we will read the content of them. then all can be done via the jszip.

but there are limitations. you can not load images from another domains. so images should be in the same url or you dynamically load them via server side like: 
`http://yourdomain.com/fileLoader.php?url=Url_To_External_Image`

here is the code snipee that do the magic:

```
function getBase64Image(imgage) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgage.width;
    canvas.height = imgage.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgage, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var img = $("<img />").attr('src', '../../../img/logo.png');

img.load(function() {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        alert('broken image!');
    }
    else {
        var zip = new JSZip();
        content = getBase64Image(img[0]);
        zip.file("24.jpg", content + "\n");
        var content = zip.generate();
        location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
    }
});
```

Comment: And there is a problem. Your solution base on my example, I mean that I will always have images. But what if I will have different type of files?

Comment: @noisy It seems you can always use something like this: 
`jQuery.get('http://yourdomain/foo.txt', function(data) {alert(data);});` to get the file content. but then again I think you can not load cross-domain files

Comment: then if you could not load the files via this method. you may want to load them in an iframe if they are some text files for example and then take the iframe content from there. what is the file types you are targeting?

Comment: @ArashMilani how to handle if I want to download files of different types (but from same server)? iframe doesnt work as it starts downloading tht file, img one cant work for non image files ie how do i handle zipping of docx or pdf or xls or etc files

Comment: @ChiragMehta Have you tried the `jQuery.get` method I mentioned in the 2nd comment. It should work as you say the file is in the same domain? certainly an `iframe` will not work for that file types as you've said.

Comment: @ArashMilani Yes i tried that too, but for some reason all GET requets are automatically getting cancelled without any more information. Ps : I'm trying to access urls which are not public, and trying to access urls which need session and the page from which I'm making these request is a logged in page with session. Is this an issue?